# How to reason about infinite values in hypothesis testing?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test

This question might not have a practical use, as infinite values rarely, if ever, come up during data analysis, but I encountered it while implementing hypothesis tests in statistical software, specifically - R.

R has special values for positive infinity (`Inf`) and negative infinity (`-Inf`). As a result users can supply these values as elements of numeric vectors to the hypothesis testing functions. And I wonder - are there any guides one can take in order to provide correct results in such cases?

For rank-based tests such as Spearman's correlation test, or Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test, the answer seems clear - the test can treat infinities as lowest/highest values and assign appropriate ranks to them.

But it's unclear to me how other tests should behave. As an example take a one sample t-test. When there is infinite value both mean and standard deviation will be infinite, and intuition tells me the test, for any finite null, should report a p-value of 0. However, the sample can contain both positive and negative infinities, and then it's not clear.

Are there any guides about reasoning with such corner cases, perhaps using a simple t-test as an example case? Or maybe the best approach is treating this as a user input error.

Comment: The problem with this question is that a user-supplied `Inf` has no definite meaning.  It could reflect a computational error, or be a mechanism to indicate `NA` values, or result from misapplication of a procedure (such as taking logarithms of zeros), or from too much floating point imprecision in a linear algebraic calculation, among many, many possibilities.  You would likely be doing most of your users a favor by causing your functions to fail as visibly as possible when presented such data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @whuber, it makes a lot of sense. But in my case I don't care about careless users and am only concerned about correct performance for the rest. Or are you saying there are no possible scenarios in which Infinity could be intended by the user intentionally?

Comment: We are defending *careful* users here! When you're releasing software for general use, the best thing you possibly can do (in addition to the usual runtime checks of the inputs) is to fail as soon and as visibly as possible when something might be remiss. Force your users to override that default if they have to. Otherwise, you can put people in the situation of getting wrong answers without knowing it merely because your software does not work in precisely the way they expect it to.  Since infinity is exceptionally rare as an actual measurement, you don't need to support it by default.